# Euler's Theorem, Homogeneous function of degree 'm'

Tags: economics, homogeneous-equation

Consider the function

$ F(x_{1}.......,x_{n}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i} ln x_{i}$

where $ \alpha _{i} $ are positive constants, and  $x_{i} \geq 1$

Does this function satisfy Euler's theorem?

Euler's theorem is

$   \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_{i}} = m f(x)$

I don't think it does, as

$  x_{1}\frac{\partial \alpha_{1} }{\partial x_{1}} ......... +   x_{n}\frac{\partial 
 \alpha_{n} }{\partial x_{n}} $   = $ ( \alpha_{1} ..... + \alpha_{n} ) $ 
so it does not satisfy eulers theroem as we dont get m f(x) , is this correct ?

also, have I differentiated correctly? Am not too sure,

Answer (score 1):

Euler's Theorem, as your title suggests, is only applicable for homogeneous functions. 
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i}ln\left ( ax_{i} \right )=ln\left ( a \right )\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i}+F\left ( \bar{x} \right )\neq aF\left ( \bar{x} \right )$
Since, $F\left ( \bar{x} \right )$ isn't homogeneous, Euler's theorem can't be applied to it.